# What is Play C.E. in Melissa K and the Heart of Gold Collector's Edition?

Tags: version-differences, melissa-k-and-the-heart-of-gold

I bought *Melissa K and the Heart of Gold Collector's Edition* and started playing, and exiting said it would save my progress. When I return to the game, the main menu offers either "Play" or "Play C.E.", where C.E. presumably means "Collector's Edition" - but what is the difference, and which one did it start me out playing by default? Are they different adventures or different saved games, or...?

I have been to the web site and searched the web but am finding no information about this.

Comment: Is there even a non collectors edition you can purchase?  I only see the CE one

Comment: @TimmyJim there should be also a "Melissa K. and the Heart of Gold HD"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I contacted the developers (SPD Games) via email, and this was their answer:

> The Collector's Edition has an additional adventure where you get to play Dr. Julian's side, along with some more collectible goodies.

So, that should be your "Play C.E." option, while the default one should be the original mode you first started.

---

As a side note, there's also a "*Melissa K. and the Heart of Gold HD*", and it's the mobile version. The game has different names when played on different platforms, as confirmed by the devs.

Comment: Thanks so much to you, and to Roddy of the Frozen Peas for adding a bounty to this, over 7 years after I asked the question!

Comment: That was unusual :) you're welcome!